# C# GUI creating a running clock while doing another task in the same form

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, clock

How can I run clock while form is open?

I am using this code:

```
DateTime present = DateTime.Now;

label1.Text = present.Hour.ToString()+ present.Minute.ToString() + present.Second.ToString();
```

I want a running clock when I open the form and should be able to click other objects while the clock is running.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problem(s) have you had with that attempt?  Explain the problems in detail.

Comment: Sorry, I am just starting to learn and dont know much of the functions in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create System.Threading.Timer object and on it's Tick event update your label text. Also it's more correct to do

```
    DateTime.Now.ToString("hhMMss");
```

or

```
    DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

instead several .ToString() calls.

The result code will be something like that

```
    new System.Threading.Timer((state) => { BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() { label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); }); }, null, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: check my second approach. Maybe it matches want you're trying.

Comment: @blacai both your solution is acceptable in WPF projects. My is in WinForms.

Comment: yes, you're right, but he should mark the chosen one as solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the class `DispatcherTimer`

```
    DispatcherTimer dpTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dpTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dpTick);
        dpTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dpTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dpTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime present = DateTime.Now;
        timer_label.Content = present.Hour.ToString() + present.Minute.ToString() + present.Second.ToString();
    }
```

If you want to use the Timer, check this solution:

```
        new System.Threading.Timer((state) => 
        {
            Action action = () => timer_label.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:MM:ss");
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
        }, null, 1000, 1000);
```